# Is it possible to shrink the clipping rectangle in Paint method?

Tags: delphi, canvas, paint

In my custom component Paint method I want to paint just a region not the whole canvas because in the other region are other objects (like a scroll bar) and I don't want to draw over them. Is it possible ? Why on Earth they make the `Canvas.ClipRect` read only ?

Comment: Hard to say, but why on Earth would you like to modify it (in the `Paint` method) ? Just copy it to a local variable and do with it what you need ;-)

Comment: In my component I have a scroll bar on the right which is drawn on the surface (canvas) of my component, and if I paint over it the flickering occurs.

Comment: I see, but you are consuming the `ClipRect` there (in the `Paint` method), so I don't see why do you want to modify it there. It is as if someone would give you a cake and you'd try to re-bake it instead of eating. It is too late, the cake is baked there (and I wouldn't call `ExcludeClipRect` there; it's *wasting of time*, it would really be enough to copy it to a local variable and exclude that rectangle from that locally stored rectangle).

Comment: I commented all the code in the Paint method and the canvas is still painted in the background color. I disabled the `wm_erasebkgnd` and now the canvas is all black, but it is still ALL painted. I want that region not by painted at all !

Comment: Well, that's a different question. The `ClipRect` you can modify by the `ExcludeClipRect` function as has been already answered (even though it makes little sense in the `Paint` method).

Comment: @marusnebunu Something has to paint it. How can it not be painted. Anyway, that is a different question. If you want help with your control's flicker ask about that. Surely I answered the question you asked. You asked how to shrink the clip rect.

Comment: @marusnebunu - Have you tried setting a hollow brush at the end of your paint method?

Comment: If your scroll bar is `TScrollBar`, it will automatically be excluded from the clipping region because that's how child controls work. If the scroll bar is a `TControlScrollBar`, then it won't even count toward your control's client area. Therefore, it sounds like you're simply doing scroll bars wrong. Take another look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ExcludeClipRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162702.aspx) to exclude regions from the clipping region. Pass the canvas `Handle` as the device context. Call the function once for each scroll bar etc. whose region you wish to exclude.

Comment: Yes, Now I can't draw on the excluded region, but it is still filled (by don't know who) with the background color and then the whole ClipRect is repainted over my scrollbar...

Comment: Well, that's going to take further investigation. You asked how to modify the clip rect. One wonders how you handle `wm_erasebkgnd` and also how you paint your scroll bars. But that's surely for a different question.